# How to install Tensorflow==1.X.X for Python2.7 on Ubuntu?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tensorflow, python-2.x

I try to install tensorflow==1.1.0 for Python2.7 with pip package manager but am getting the following error when I run the command pip install tensorflow:

```
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip can be found at pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/… pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==1.1.0 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==1.1.0
```

How else can I install tensorflow for Python2.7?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you please post the full error message? [TF 1.1.0 is available on PyPI.](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/1.1.0/)

Comment: I think it's not supported for Python2.7

Comment: pip install tensorflow==1.1.0
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==1.1.0 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==1.1.0

Comment: @FaziletGokbudak Have you installed a 64-bit Version of Python?

Comment: @ai2ys yes, I have.

Answer (score -1):

You could use a ready to use Docker image.
https://hub.docker.com/r/tensorflow/tensorflow/tags?page=1&name=1.1.0

The tags with the postfix ”py3“ indicate using Python 3.x while the ones without this postfix are using Python 2.7.

Here some additional information about the Docker images. https://hub.docker.com/r/tensorflow/tensorflow/

Dockerfiles for TF 1.1.0 https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/v1.1.0/tensorflow/tools/docker

Comment: Thank you! I would rather prefer an easier way as I already create a Python virtualenv in my virtual machine to install all required packages.

Comment: @FaziletGokbudak using Docker you woudn‘t need a VM at all. I personally prefer using Docker as it will encapsulate Cuda versions as well.

Comment: I need to run the code in my VM as I only have access to GPUs in the university's cloud services. So, I'll wait for a while for some other answers before trying Docker. Thank you so much!